# How do I pass mutiple column names to Perl Dancer's quick_select method?

Tags: perl, dancer

I'm trying to use Perl Dancer `quick_select` to quickly fetch rows from the database. I'm using a list of items from the user that I got like this: `my @arr=split(/,/, $inline);`

I keep getting this error when using the items from the user:

> `DBD::mysql::db selectall_arrayref failed: Unknown column 'val2' in 'where clause'`

This does not work:

```
my @rows = $connect->quick_select('table', { column => @arr});
```

But this does work:

```
my @rows = $connect->quick_select('table', { column => ['val1', 'val2']});`
```

Apparently `[]` denotes a list but `@arr` is an array in Perl? So I've tried converting it to a list but this also does not work:

```
my @rows = $connect->quick_select('table', { column => @arr[0..$#arr]});
```

The table and column names have been changed to protect the data. How can I fix this so `quick_select` will work with dynamic data from the user?

Comment: Dancer doesn't have a `quick_select` function. I assume you're using a Dancer plugin to add that to your program. It would be helpful if you could tell us where it comes from.

Answer (score 3):

> Apparently `[]` denotes a list but `@arr` is an array in Perl? So I've tried converting it to a list but this also does not work.

That's not correct. `[]` denotes an array reference in Perl. An array is an ordered list of scalars indexed by number, and an array reference is a scalar that "points to" an array.

You can take the array you scoop up from `$input`, take a reference to it with the `\@array` syntax, and send it in that way:

```
my @rows = $connect->quick_select('table', { column => \@arr});
```

You can take that one step further (at possibly some cost to clarity) by forcing the call to `split` into an array reference inline:

```
my @rows = $connect->quick_select('table', { column => [split(/,/, $inline)] });
```

Comment: Nice that worked! Thanks! I usually don't use Perl, all these symbols can be confusing.

Comment: *"An array is a list"* No, it is not. Arrays and lists are [very different things](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array%3f).

Comment: @Borodin I was updating to say "a type of list" while you were typing that.

Comment: @stevieb: I don't agree with that either.

Comment: @Borodin How's "an array is a variable that can hold a list of values"?

Comment: See `perldoc perldata`: "*arrays are ordered lists of scalars indexed by number*".

Comment: Updated to reflect the quote from `perldata`.